# Pick values from text file and put them after string

Tags: bash, sed

I'd like to pick two values from the text file and paste it to another file after certain strings:

```
#!/bin/bash
IAM_ROLE=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials)
curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/$IAM_ROLE | jq -r '.AccessKeyId, .SecretAccessKey' > /tmp/aws_credentials
curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .region > /tmp/aws_region

{ read -r val1
  read -r val2
  sed -i 's! access_key= .* *$! access_key= $val1 !; s! secret_key= .* *$! secret_key= $val2 !;' /etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config
} < /tmp/aws_credentials
```

/etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config looks like:

```
access_key=
secret_key=
version=4
v4-region-map=region_map.config
```

However sed part of the script is doing nothing.

Comment: shell variables does not expand within single quotes for starters

Comment: I've tried with and without. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? put an echo before the `sed` command and remove the `-i`,  if that does tell you what's wrong execute your script with the `-x` option

Comment: You should search for this pattern `!access_key=*$!`  also instead of single quote use `"`

Comment: @DigvijayS If I change sed line to: `sed -i "s! !access_key=*$! access_key=$val1 !; s! !secret_key=*$! secret_key=$val2 !;" /etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config` and also add set -x to get the output I can see that the sed can see the values from in the source file but not pasting it to the the s3_auth_v4.config file: `sed -i 's! !access_key=* access_key=REDACTED !; s! !secret_key=* secret_key=REDACTED !;' /etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config`

Comment: Try `s!access_key=.*$! access_key=$val1 !`  You are using `!` as delimiter sed works like `s!search pattern!replace pattern!occurence`  If you want to see what pattern you are selecting you can used `&`. For example try `echo "123abc123" | sed 's![a-z]!(&)!'` and `echo "123abc123" | sed 's! [a-z]!(&)!'` you can see due to extra space  pattern is not matching

Comment: @DigvijayS that doesn't work at all: `sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'` for sed line like: `sed -i "s!access_key=.*$! access_key=$val1 ! s!secret_key=.*$! secret_key=$val2 !" /etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config`

Comment: `sed -i "s!access_key=.*$! access_key=$val1 !; s!secret_key=.*$! secret_key=$val2 !;" /etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config` You have removed `;`

Comment: @DigvijayS That doesn't work either: `sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unknown option to `s'`